# Align environment Error

Tags: align

I am getting error as: LaTeX Error: Environment align* undefined.

```
\begin{align*}
F &= \frac{AE\delta t}{t} \intertext{Newton} \\
E &= \frac{Stress}{Strain} = \frac{F}{A}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\delta t}{t}}\\
&= \frac{Ft}{A\delta t} \intertext{N/m^2}\\
\intertext{The charge at the elctrode give riseto an output voltage $E_{0}$} \\
Voltage(E_{0}) &= \frac{Q}{C_p}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: also `\frac{Stress}{Strain}` should be `\frac{\mathrm{Stress}}{\mathrm{Strain}}`

Comment: It says: ! Missing $ inserted.

Comment: Change `\intertext{N/m^2}` to `\intertext{$N/m^2$}`. Also, you should almost certainly be using `\Delta` instead of `\delta`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, you need to load the `amsmath` package in the preamble. Assuming you want to stick with the `\intertext` approach, you will also need to change `\intertext{N/m^2}` to `\intertext{$N/m^2$}`.

However, you probably shouldn't be employing `\intertext{...}` at all in two of the three cases. Instead, consider using `\tag*{...}`. To typeset physical units, do look into using the `siunitx` package and its `\si` macro. Finally, variable names should generally be written using the upright text-mode font, not the math-italic font.

Finally, do change `\delta` to `\Delta` (3 instances).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\textnormal{#1}} % "\vn" is short for "variable name"
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
F &= \frac{AE\Delta t}{t}  \tag*{Newton}\\
E &= \frac{\vn{Stress}}{\vn{Strain}} = \frac{F}{A}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{\Delta t}{t}}\\
&= \frac{Ft}{A\Delta t} \tag*{\si{\newton\per\meter\squared}} \\
\intertext{The charge at the electrode gives rise to an output voltage $E_{0}$.} 
\vn{Voltage } E_{0} &= \frac{Q}{C_p}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```